# Get a UFILE back to one of its previous state

Tags: c++, file, io, icu

I am currently using the ICU library for parsing some Unicode text in C++. The parser may fail, so when it fails I need a rollback. For example, we might want to match a sequence `aaab`, but after the `aaa` we get a `c`, then the whole matching fails, and logically we should roll back to just before the first `a`, and prepare for a next matching.

I know when we are using a `FILE *` in `<stdio.h>`, we can just seek the file pointer to a place we save in advance.

```
FILE* file = fopen("...", "r");
long pos = ftell(file);
// ... read some characters from (FILE *) file
fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

I tried this in `ICU`, using the `u_fgetfile` function to get a `FILE *` from `UFILE`, and seek the file pointer in that `FILE *`.

```
UFILE* file = u_fopen("...", "r", nullptr, nullptr);
FILE* internal_file = u_fgetfile(file);
long pos = ftell(internal_file);
// ... read some characters from (UFILE *) file
fseek(file, pos, SEEK_SET);
```

But in my test cases, it turns out that the file pointer (returned from `ftell`) is always at the end of the file. Since the file I tested with is a rather small file (only 16 characters is in the file), I guess that `ICU` has read the file before I required it to read, and then cached the result, so the file pointer in `FILE` is not synchronized with the current position I am reading from.

Also, the [documentation](http://icu-project.org/apiref/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html#a254f86265efa9b9e8e9683aa5bccdb7c) of `ICU` said that

> The FILE must not be modified or closed

So I guess I am not allowed to seek the file pointer of the `FILE`.

It is quite difficult to keep track of all the characters I read from the `UFILE`, for it is scattered in tens of functions. So I cannot think of a way to use `u_fungetc` since it requires me to know what character I want to put back. Also, calling `u_fungetc` means linear time for rolling back, so I wonder whether there is a faster method.

So is it possible to somehow save the status of a `UFILE`, and recover to that state after reading some characters from it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems that nobody is going to answer this question, so I am here to give my temporary solution, in case that anyone might need it.

I will just use a ring buffer for cache, and use the cache instead of directly using the `UFILE`.