# Passing FILE* from fopen in stdio.h to u_finit in ustdio.h then call u_fgetc will trigger unhandled exception error for u_fgetc

Tags: c, file, unicode, icu

This is what confused me so far. Apparently passing `FILE*` from `fopen` in `stdio.h` to `u_finit` in `ustdio.h` then call `u_fgetc` will trigger unhandled exception error for `u_fgetc` (`file` and `ufile` have NULL check in my actual code)

But looks like instead of that I just call `u_fopen` then `u_fgetc` will works as expected.

```c
FILE* file = fopen("path/to/file.txt", "rb"); // Apparently both "r" and "rb" will have same issue
UFILE* ufile = u_finit(file, NULL, NULL);
UChar uchar = u_fgetc(ufile);
```

Did I do something wrong? The ICU documentation said I can pass `FILE*` to `f_init` but nothing mentions about unhandled exception error ([docs link](https://unicode-org.github.io/icu-docs/apidoc/released/icu4c/ustdio_8h.html)).

The assertion error happened on Visual Studio 2022. In gcc the program simply crash (nothing, even there's no `Segmentation Fault`).

Why do I want to do this? because there's no equivalent to `ftell`, `fseek` and `fgetpos`, `fsetpos` in icu. Also looks like someone asked [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50987901/get-a-ufile-back-to-one-of-its-previous-state) before but no answer to it beside the "hack" answer. I have tried to call `fgetpos` on `u_fgetfile` but it also cause assert error. Probably I should open separate question in regard to this.

Comment: Did `fopen` actually succeed?  I can imagine `u_finit` expects a non-NULL pointer.  The documentation doesn't say anything about this, but if I was implementing such a function I would assume the caller has done basic error checking.

Comment: You must make sure that the `fopen()` succeeds (by checking that the return value is not null).

Comment: Yes, I guaranteed it succeed in my code for NULL check, however I ommited the NULL check in the question for shorten the example.

Comment: @paddy according to documentation, `u_finit()` will take default locale args if NULL provided. So, this should be fine.

Comment: @Kamiccolo I'm wasn't talking about the locale; I was talking about the `FILE` pointer.

Comment: sorry, my bad :}

@Trung0246 generic concensus on SO is to provide minimal sample which can actually compile.